# Handling bash system variables and slurm environmental variables in a wrapper script

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, wrapper, slurm

**Problem**: Inspired by this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129391/passing-named-arguments-to-shell-scripts), I'm trying to write a wrapper script that submits SLURM array jobs with bash variables. However, I'm running into issues with SLURM environment variables like `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` as it acts as an empty variable.

I suspect it has something to do with how the `test_wrapper.sh` is parsing the *yet undefined* SLURM variable, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Below I provide a working example with a simple python script that should take an array ID as an input variable, but when it is called by the bash wrapper script, the python script crashes as it receives an empty variable.

`test_wrapper.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
for argument in "$@"
do
  key=$(echo $argument | cut -f 1 -d'=')
  value=$(echo $argument | cut -f 2 -d'=')
  case "$key" in
    "job_name")     job_name="$value" ;;
    "cpus")         cpus="$value" ;;
    "memory")       memory="$value" ;;
    "time")         time="$value" ;;
    "array")        array="$value" ;;
    *)
  esac
done

sbatch <<EOT
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --account=foobar
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=${cpus:-1}
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=${memory:-1}GB
#SBATCH --time=${time:-00:01:00}
#SBATCH --array=${array:-1-2}
#SBATCH --job-name=${job_name:-Default_Job_Name}

if [ -z "$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID" ]
then
      echo "The array ID \$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is empty"
else
      echo "The array ID \$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is NOT empty"
fi

srun python foo.py -a $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

echo "Job finished with exit code $?"

EOT
```

where `foo.py` is:

```
import argparse

def main(args):
  print('array number is : {}'.format(args.array_number))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--array_number",
        help="the value passed from SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"
        )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

`$cat slurm-123456789_1.out` yields :

```
The array ID 1 is empty
usage: foo.py [-h] [-a ARRAY_NUMBER]
foo.py: error: argument -a/--array_number: expected one argument
srun: error: nc10931: task 0: Exited with exit code 2
Job finished with exit code 0
```

I find it strange, that "The array ID 1 is empty" is correctly printing the `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` (??)

Comment: It might be helpful here to collect xtrace logs -- extending `test_wrapper.sh` to, after the shebang, run `exec 2>trace.log; PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x` and then reviewing `trace.log` will at least let you see what's going on in the loop that iterates over arguments.

Comment: ...if you replaced `sbatch <<EOT` with `{ tee /dev/stderr | sbatch; } <<EOT`, then your trace log would _also_ contain the script as it's being passed to `sbatch`.

Comment: Not sure where to run the `exec 2>trace.log; PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x` mentioned in the first comment.

as suggested in 2nd comment:

```
$ bash test_wrapper.sh 
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --account=foobar
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1GB
#SBATCH --time=00:01:00
#SBATCH --array=1-2
#SBATCH --job-name=Default_Job_Name

if [ -z "" ]
then
      echo "The array ID $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is empty"
else
      echo "The array ID $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is NOT empty"
fi

srun python foo.py -a 

echo "Job finished with exit code 0"

Submitted batch job 9519024

```

Comment: Why do you only escape $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID in some places and not others? The unescaped ones are being substituted before the heredoc is given to sbatch. Is that variable perhaps being set by sbatch as part of executing the script?

Comment: There's a similar issue in your log where srun says it exited with exit code 2, but then you print `Job finished with exit code 0` because $? is substituted before sbatch receives the script. Perhaps you want to prevent parameter expansions by quoting `<<"EOT"`?

Comment: The line from the first comment was to add into the top of the `test_wrapper.sh` script (as that comment said). As comments don't preserve whitespace, extra content should be [edit]ed into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to [this page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html):

> Job arrays will have two additional environment variable set. SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID will be set to the first job ID of the array. SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID will be set to the job array index value.

That suggests to me that `sbatch` is supposed to set these for you. In that case, you need to escape all instances of `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` in the script you pass via the heredoc so that they don't get prematurely substituted before `sbatch` can set the relevant environment variable.

The two options for this are:

1. If you don't want any expansions to occur at all, quote the heredoc delimiter.

```
sbatch <<"EOT"
<your script here>
EOT
```

2. If you need some expansions to occur but want to disable others, then escape the ones that should not be expanded by putting a `\` in front of them like you have done in your existing script.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the feedback posted in the comments I was able to fix the issue. Posting a "fixed" version of the wrapper script below.

In short, the solution is to escape $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID.

```
#!/bin/bash
for argument in "$@"
do
  key=$(echo $argument | cut -f 1 -d'=')
  value=$(echo $argument | cut -f 2 -d'=')
  case "$key" in
    "job_name")     job_name="$value" ;;
    "cpus")         cpus="$value" ;;
    "memory")       memory="$value" ;;
    "time")         time="$value" ;;
    "array")        array="$value" ;;
    *)
  esac
done

{ tee /dev/stderr | sbatch; } <<EOT
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --account=foobar
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=${cpus:-1}
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=${memory:-1}GB
#SBATCH --time=${time:-00:01:00}
#SBATCH --array=${array:-1-2}
#SBATCH --job-name=${job_name:-Default_Job_Name}

if [ -z "\$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID" ]
then
      echo "The array ID \$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is empty"
else
      echo "The array ID \$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is NOT empty"
fi

python foo.py -a \$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

EOT
```

`cat slurm-123456789_1.out` yields :

```
The array ID 1 is NOT empty
array number is : 1
```

Note: the `{ tee /dev/stderr | sbatch; }` is not necessary, but is very useful for debugging (thanks Charles Duffy)